# After imaging Linux and restore are password broken but actually not

Tags: centos, password, images

I have a weird issue on Centos 7.5-18.04
I have a freshly installed system with accounts added for ssh.
The image is done with clonezilla.
Restoring the image works fine but the passwords of the ssh accounts behave funny.

ssh connections get rejected. The ssh log show a wrong password.
Testing the accounts by logging on show the same result.

Setting a "new" (the old) password get confirmed with a message stating the history has not been updated with the old password as no different/new password has been added.

But now it works fine.
It is no real big thing but an annoyance. I make an image to do all the work once upfront and not fixing it afterwards.

Any thought about what is happening?

Cheers
Jan

Comment: Are they normal system users? But you can physically login(without ssh)?

Comment: They are normal users but they cannot log on interactive

Comment: Can you post an `/etc/passwd` user example before and after resetting the password? You can do `cat /etc/passwd` and select a user that is affected. You might not want to post the username itself for security reasons. In addition to that you should check `/etc/shadow` for an affected user before and after resetting and see if something changes. (Especially the hash but also other parameters). But I wouldn't recommend posting the password hash from the shadow file. The rest should be fine.